# How do I get Max date from these SQL Tables

Tags: sql, join

I need to list all students with their DESC.

Steps of algorithm:

1. In table STUDENT_TYPE, for every student, get the TYPE_ID for the record with maximum DT_OF_WORK date.
2. With the TYPE_ID found, get the DESC from table STUDENT_DESC
3. List all students from STUDENT with their DESC.

Here are the three SQL tables.

Table `STUDENT_TYPE`

Primary key is: (`Student_ID, DT_OF_WORK`)

```
|Student_ID  |  TYPE_ID  |  DT_OF_WORK  |  CATEGORY|
|         1  |        1  |  01-JAN-2017 |         B|
|         1  |        2  |  11-JAN-2017 |         A|
|         1  |        1  |  02-JAN-2017 |         A|
|         1  |        1  |  03-JAN-2017 |         A|
|         3  |        2  |  16-JAN-2017 |         A|
|         3  |        1  |  03-JAN-2014 |         A|
|         3  |        1  |  23-JAN-2012 |         A|
|         4  |        2  |  02-JAN-2013 |         A|
```

Table `STUDENT_DESC`

```
|TYPE_ID|DESC  |
|      1|LEAD  |
|      2|TOPPER|
```

Table `STUDENT`:

```
|STUDENT_ID|NAME  |
|         1|JACK  |
|         2|RAVI  |
|         3|SEENU |
|         4|RAM   |
```

- Student_ID (STUDENT_TYPE) = STUDENT_ID (Student)
- TYPE_ID (STUDENT_TYPE) = TYPE_ID (STUDENT_DESC)

Desired output:

```
|STUDENT_ID|NAME  |DESC  |
|         1|JACK  |LEAD  |
|         2|RAVI  |null  |
|         3|SEENU |TOPPER|
|         4|RAM   |TOPPER|
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL? Postgresql? Sql Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's **several** different ways that you can accomplish this. And since you didn't specify which database engine, I assumed SQL Server.

Given how large your tables are this may not be the most performant, but this should do the trick:

```
WITH    Rankings
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     ( SELECT    st.Student_ID
                                  , st.Type_Id
                                  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY st.Student_ID ORDER BY st.DT_Of_Work DESC ) AS RowNumber
                          FROM      Student_Type AS st ) q
               WHERE    q.RowNumber = 1)
    SELECT  s.Student_Id
          , s.Name
          , d.[Desc]
    FROM    Student s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Rankings c
    ON      s.Student_Id = c.Student_Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Student_Desc d
    ON      d.Type_ID = c.Type_ID;
```

This effectively works by splitting the rows and giving them a number based on the partition and the order by in the [ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function. We then select the lowest (with the value of `1`), and using it to determine the most current `Type_Id`. With the help of a few [outer joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/), we can get all the data.

Side note: Your expected output is incorrect. Jack's `DESC` should be `TOPPER`.